# No EJB receiver available for handling on jboss - Only in new Thread

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.1

In this code:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
System.out.println("AB");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    final LancadorDeDado lancadorTeste = (LancadorDeDado) ctx.lookup("dadoWeb/LancadorDeDadoBean!br.com.k19.sessionbeans.LancadorDeDado");
    System.out.println("Dado: " + lancadorTeste.lanca());
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                System.out.println("Dado Nova Thread: " + lancadorTeste.lanca());
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

the line:

```
System.out.println("Dado: " + lancadorTeste.lanca());
```

whorks fine, but the line:

```
System.out.println("Dado Nova Thread: " + lancadorTeste.lanca());
```

doen't work and say this execption:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:,modulename:dadoWeb,distinctname:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@15def7ff
```

Whats wrong?!

Tanks

DRauber!